# Android, YouTube API - How to make the video change on a button press

Tags: java, android, api, youtube

I want to make an app, and part of that app has to do with the YouTube Data API.I set that up, and managed to make the video appear and play when the button is pressed.But I want the video to change to another video when I press the button again.
I have a String array with all my videos.
Here is my code:

```
public class HomeScreen extends YouTubeBaseActivity {
private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
private YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/title.ttf");
    TextView titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleText);
    titleText.setTypeface(tf);
    titleText.setText(R.string.app_name);
    titleText.setTextSize(30);
    Button b;
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final theList list = new theList();
    videoList.add("code here");
    videoList.add("code here");
    videoList.add("code here");
    videoList.add("code here");
    final Random r = new Random();
    youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.view);
    onInitializedListener = new OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            int i1 = r.nextInt(videoList.getIncrement() - 0) + 0;
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoList.getLink());

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    };

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            youTubePlayerView.initialize("282906853585-nrprlo5qkiervdst29262phctlb6hcd5.apps.googleusercontent.com", onInitializedListener);
        }
    });


}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't initialize youtube player again and again. Instead, add a globe reference to YouTubePlayer and assign it in onInitializationSuccess. and use that YouTubePlayer instance to change the video.

Hope it helps!

`

```
public class HomeScreen extends YouTubeBaseActivity {   
private YouTubePlayerView mYouTubePlayerView;
private YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener mOnInitializedListener;
private  YouTubePlayer mYouTubePlayer;
private Button mButton;


private final String VIDEO_CODE="replace with video code";
private final String API_KEY="replace with your API key ";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    youTubePlayerSetup();
    mButton  = findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mYouTubePlayer.cueVideo("replace with new video code");
        }
    });
}

private void youTubePlayerSetup(){

    mYouTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
    mOnInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            if(!b){
                mYouTubePlayer =youTubePlayer;
                mYouTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO_CODE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    };

    mYouTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY,mOnInitializedListener);
}}
```

`